How to avoid making errors in a research position
I've been hired recently to perform calculations for a new device's feasibility, to judge whether or not to proceed with the project.  The calculations are pretty involved, with lots of simulations, statistics, and code.  I invested a lot of time in this project, working long into evenings and weekends, and checked my work several times (using different methods wherever I could create them). I've kept the team updated on my work, though I mainly share my results and not the details of my calculations.  It seemed like the device was promising.
Two days ago, however, as I was explaining my work to my supervisor he pointed out that one of my assumptions was incorrect, an assumption that I thought to be innocuous.  I re-carried out the simulations and it ended up completely changing the result of one of my calculations.  This is going to have a big impact on the project:  we've already gone forward with some purchases, and the error is completely on me.
I'm going to discuss the error with my supervisor as soon as I get back to work, but in the meantime I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong.  I find that when I'm doing long calculations I'll have made an error where I've least expected it, and no matter how many times I check my work some mistakes will still appear.  This is a problem I've noticed I've had since grad school.  How do I avoid making these types of errors in the future?  There are so many moving parts to these calculations, I always seem to end up screwing up somewhere.  Also, any advice on how to best handle the situation at work would be appreciated.  I'm worried I'm going to be let go, and what that would mean for my future prospects.

VTC - Fundamentally, this is not a workplace question. The degree to which assumptions are either reasonable or unreasonable and the consequences for these assumptions varies wildly between work fields. A Reasonable assumption for IT might be catastrophic in Engineering.

Everybody makes mistakes.  The things you think are hardest are the ones you spend most time getting right.  So it tends to be the "easy" things that are wrong.  The way you avoid that becoming a problem is peer review.
Show your calculations to your supervisor, or to a co-worker who is experienced enough to understand them, before making any commitments based on the reults.

That's not an uncommon thing to happen when science meets real world. Accept the error and try to learn from it. However there are methods to help with that type of task:

Break down your model into as many small self contained independent modules as possible.
Test and verify each module individually. Don't even think about putting the whole thing together before all the individual bits and pieces are verified. That's similar to "unit testing" in software development.
Then integrate the model and do as much experimental or data based verification as is feasible.
Create a list of all underlying assumption with a rationale and a confidence rating. If needed set a range for a specific assumption
Run a variability analysis. i.e. deter mine which assumptions or parameter have the largest impact on the result.
Deep dive into the assumptions/parameters that your model is most sensitive too.
Frequently review your design, test results, assumptions and variability analysis with subject matter experts and stakeholders. Make sure the reviews are not "dumps" but well prepared, concise and with clear goals and objectives. Expert and stakeholder time is hard to come by: make sure everyone feels its time well used.


"How do I avoid making these types of errors in the future?" Learn from your mistakes and never make the same mistake twice. Everyone makes errors, but as you learn and grow throughout your career the unfamiliar stuff that you struggle with now will become second nature. Like how your supervisor identified your error right away. It is ultimately up to your employer/manager/department head, etc, to decide how much responsibility someone is ready for and deploy their resources appropriately.

You can't. And that's okay.

It is okay to make mistakes, they are a part of the scientific process. Penicillin was discovered because of a mistake, and has saved countless lives.
In fact its a bad idea to try to avoid all errors, look at Amazon's Blue Origin they have spent 20+ billion now and still haven't launched a rocket, because they want it to 'work'. Meanwhile space X has rockets blow up on launch pads, crash-land, land then fall over and explode etc... Space X learns thru its million dollar mistakes, while amazon learns less from billions of dollars due to their fear of making a mistake.
So what do I do?

Do what you recently did. Have a regular meeting with your supervisor where you explain what you are doing/what you plan to do, daily, weekly, biweekly... The shortest interval that you will have somethign new to discuss/showoff. I would definetly sitdown with your supervisor before a large purchase.
This is helpful because your supervisors larger repertoire of past mistakes (a.k.a life experiences) helps them to see things that you have missed.
